# A type of word or idiom by which the heart breaks

Tags: word-request, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiom-request

Example:

"My cruel friend spoke in such a way that it broke my heart"

Another example:

"Also I know deception and___word that can break your heart"

What type of word did he speak, which broke the heart? I want that word instead of 'In such a way' or fill the blank  space

Comment: Please explain why [heartbreakingly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heartbreakingly) doesn't meet your requirement.

Comment: An _H word_? :)

Comment: Insulting or offensive

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Even though you wrote *or* in *"I want that word instead of 'In such a way' or fill the blank space"*, perhaps you meant to be *and* (it sounds so to me). And because *My cruel friend spoke [in such a way] that it broke my heart* needs something adverb-like, while *Also I know deception and [something here] word that can break your heart* needs something adjective-like, your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this fits: *“... words that **cut you to the bone** and break your heart.”*

> **cut someone to the bone/heart/quick**
>
> to say or do something unkind that makes someone feel very upset
>   *His mockery, which he meant as a joke, cut her to the bone*.
>
> <sub>[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cut-someone-to-the-bone-heart-quick)</sub>

Use the verb, cut, change it into an adverb and:

> My cruel friend spoke so **cuttingly**, it broke my heart.
>
> **Adv.**   1.  *cuttingly* - in an intentionally unkind way; "a cutting remark"
>
> <sub>[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cuttingly)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for ***heartbreaking*** :

> - causing great sadness, disappointment, etc.
>
>   - *a heartbreaking story*
>   - *It is heartbreaking (for him) that he cannot see his children.*

Comment: It's not as I require above

Comment: @Arman - can you please clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Is that Acerbic suitable in that situation?